# Como passar um parâmetro de uma page para um provider no ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic3, ip

Bom dia , gostaria de saber se é possível  definir o endereço de ip ao consumir um web service rest no ionic 3, onde o usuário poderia definir o endereço e a porta a qual estaria a api. O usuário  definiria o endereço ip na page , por exemplo "192.168.1" e seria preciso passar esse valor para o provider , exemplo "rest_usuario = 'http://192.168.1/WebService/usuarios'". Tentei utilizar sessão mas não funciona, o localstorage funciona, mas é preciso reiniciar o app novamente. Esse endereço ip está salvo em uma tabela no sqlite.

configuracao.html

```
<form padding [formGroup]="configuracaoForm" (submit)="Enviar()" novalidate>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Endereço IP</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.ip" formControlName="ip" placeholder="Endereço IP"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <br>
```

configuracao.ts

```
Enviar() {
    return this.dbProvider.getDB()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        let sql = 'select * from configuracao where endereco_ip =?',
          data = [this.model.ip];
        return db.executeSql(sql, data)
          .then((data: any) => {
            if (data.rows.length > 0) {
              let config: any[] = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                var configuracao = data.rows.item(i);
                config.push(configuracao);
                localStorage.setItem("ip", this.model.ip)
```

rest.ts

```
insereUsuario() {
    // this.endereco = window.sessionStorage.getItem('endereco');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://' + localStorage.getItem("ip") + '/WebService/usuarios').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um provider com algum nome do tipo constants.provider.ts e crie metodos de get e set. Veja abaixo:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConstantesProvider {
    private url: string;
    private link: string;
    constructor(){
      this.url = '/WebService/usuarios'; 
      this.link = '';
    }

}

public setLink(url:string){
    this.link = url;
}

public getUrl(){
    return this.link.concat(this.url);
}
```

Dentro de configuracao.ts você chama o método setLink() passando a url como parametro:

```
import {ConstantesProvider } from 'caminho/para/o/seu/provider';

constructor(constProvider: ConstantesProvider ){}
Enviar() {
    return this.dbProvider.getDB()
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        let sql = 'select * from configuracao where endereco_ip =?',
          data = [this.model.ip];
        return db.executeSql(sql, data)
          .then((data: any) => {
            if (data.rows.length > 0) {
              let config: any[] = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                var configuracao = data.rows.item(i);
                config.push(configuracao);
                this.constProvider.setLink(this.model.ip)
```

E finalmente dentro do seu rest.ts vc chama o método getUrl():

```
import {ConstantesProvider } from 'caminho/para/o/seu/provider';

constructor(constProvider: ConstantesProvider ){}

insereUsuario() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.constProvider.getUrl()).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Não esqueça de importar o `ConstantesProvider`  dentro de app.module.ts, se estiver utilizando lazyloading, importe o `ConstantesProvider` dentro do modulo em questão.

Recomendo a utilização dos Observables, porém é necessário ler sobre. Separei dois links que me ajudaram a entender. [Aqui](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-observable-ou-promise-34392) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable)

Comment: Muto obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: verifica se o endereço de IP está correto. 192.168.1 está incompleto. Exemplo de um IP completo: 192.168.0.1

Comment: Entendi. Primeiro vc precisa definir um endereço de IP padrão ou antes de criar a tabela e inserir os dados, vc pede para o usuario colocar o IP.